# Horizontal scrollbar for asp.net ajax Tabcontainer

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, scrollbar, tabcontainer

I have working with asp.net ajax tabcontainer with multiple tabs that are not fit in single row. I want scroll  to my tab container  like  below image. Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBmcd.png

Comment: Add Div in all tab set its width according to tab and overflow in style property.